# Converting a non-lettered partition from FAT32 to NTFS

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, conversion, bitlocker, fat32

I'm working on setting up BitLocker in Server 2012.  After enabling TPS in BIOS, I attempted to enable Bitlocker.  The following error appeared:

> BitLocker Drive Encryption operating system drives must be formatted
>   with the NTFS file system in order to be encrypted. Convert the drive
>   to NTFS, and then turn on BitLocker

I then went to Disk Management and discovered two partitions without drive letters.  One of these is FAT32, the other is an OEM Partition.

[image: Disk Management shows two non-lettered partitions]

Is it safe to convert the 2.00 GB FAT32 partition to NTFS on the fly?  Will I lose data or cause the system to no longer boot?

Comment: Took a bit of a risk and convert it after reading where another person did so successfully.   Rebooted and all is well (and the partition is now NTFS).

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: Is that the reason for the downvote?  Really?

Comment: down votes are anonymous and are only opinions. You need to post your comment as an answer, then you can accept it as a solution in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and converted the unlettered "OS" partition as follows:

1. Right click partition in Disk Management and assign a temporary drive letter Z.
2. Converted drive Z ("OS" partition) from FAT32 to NTFS.
3. Removed drive letter Z from "OS" partition.
4. Rebooted

All is well.  I was then able to configure and enable Bitlocker.